# jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin not excluding "assets" directory created by jekyll-assets

Tags: internationalization, jekyll, assets, jekyll-extensions

I have the [jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin](https://github.com/screeninteraction/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin) and [jekyll-assets](https://github.com/jekyll-assets/jekyll-assets) plugins installed in a new Jekyll app. I have the following in my `_config.yml`:

```
languages: ['en', 'es']
exclude_from_localizations: ['assets']
```

The assets configuration is all defaults.

When I build the site, I end up with `_site/assets` *and* `_site/es/assets`. Not sure if these plugins play well together, but am I missing something? How can I get jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin to exclude the directory created by jekyll-assets in all the additional localizations?

Here is the sample app: https://github.com/robertwbradford/jekyll-assets-and-multiple-languages